# how to know which account write into my fusion tables

Tags: gmail, google-fusion-tables, verify, app-inventor

hi im inventing an apps using Appinventor and user need to login with their gmail account so that they can write into my fusion tables. my fusion tables have a list of permission of which email can write into it. so i want to know how is they way to know who (which email account) write into my fusion table. any tutorial or guidance? or clue would be really appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2571232?hl=en&ref_topic=2811744) help page on fusion tables will help, though I couldn't locate your exact problem anywhere